Java Request SOAP. NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces
Estoy intentando en Java crear la siguiente request para SOAP:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ent="https://loginserviciosgeneral.servicio>
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <ent:LoginServiciosGeneralIn>
        <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:mensajeWS xmlns:ns2="https://webservices/3.27">
    <solicitudLoginServiciosGeneral>
        <idAplicacion>idAplicacion</idAplicacion>
        <firmaAplicacion>firmaAplicacion</firmaAplicacion>
    </solicitudLoginServiciosGeneral>
</ns2:mensajeWS>]]>
      </ent:LoginServiciosGeneralIn>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Para eso tengo la siguiente clase:
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        //Crear el contexto WSDL
        try {
            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ent", "https://loginserviciosgeneral.servicio");
            SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
            header.setPrefix("soapenv");
            
            //Crear el cuerpo WSDL
            SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
            soapBody.setPrefix("soapenv");
            SOAPElement bodyElement = soapBody.addChildElement("LoginServiciosGeneralIn");
            bodyElement.setPrefix("ent");
            String valor = construirCData();
            System.out.println(valor);
            
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

Pero en la linea bodyElement.setPrefix("ent") me sale el siguiente error:

Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An
attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is
incorrect with regard to namespaces.  at
org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl.setPrefix(Unknown Source)     at
com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.xmlsoap.SOAPElement.setPrefix(SOAPElement.java:2092)
at paquetePrueba.WsdlClient.main(WsdlClient.java:36)

Me gustaría saber cómo arreglar esto.
Muchas gracias.
Un saludo.
